# PyMongo collection name behaving strangely in cython

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, cython

So I was experiencing some strange behaviour using the pymongo API for mongodb in cython.

```
def pull_data(connection, context, data_id):
    collection_name = "%s-%s" % (COLLECTION_MODIFIER, context.sc_id)
    collection = connection[DBNAME][collection_name]
    query = {ID_KEY:data_id}
    json_data = collection.find_one(query)
    return json_data, collection
```

If I `%paste` this at the command line I get exactly what I expected:

```
In [66]: pull_data(conn, sc, 123)
Out[66]: 
{u'_id': 123,
 u'l': Binary("cnumpy.core.multi [...]
```

However if I make exactly the same function call within a cython extension the record is not found.

The only difference I can find between the two is something to do with the collection name:

```
#collection generated in shell call
Collection(Database(Connection('localhost', 27017), u'db'), u'coll-0') 
#collection generated in cython call
Collection(Database(Connection('localhost', 27017), u'db'), u'db.coll-0')
```

If I try to make a collection with the same signature in the shell it similarly can't find the record.

Any clues as to what is going on, or how to force searching within the correct collection?

EDIT: the `COLLECTION_MODIFIER = 'coll'` is the same in both cases.

Also, hardcoding in the form of `coll = conn.db1.coll0` after dropping the hyphen produces the same sort of problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that

```
collection_name = "%s-%s" % (COLLECTION_MODIFIER, context.sc_id)
```

produces `'coll-0'` in the shell, and `'db.coll-0'` in the call.  It looks like `sc.sc_id` is `0` in both cases. but `COLLECTION_MODIFIER` is different, `coll` in one, `db.coll` in the other.

But you don't show us either of these values, or how they are set, so I can only guess.

Comment: It's `COLLECTION_MODIFIER = "coll"` in both cases.